# Java Axis client creates double Security header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I'm using Axis 1.x client to invoke a web service (SOAP). After generating the stubs, I'm able to invoke the web service but get an authentication error due to no username/password. All attempts to set username and password on stub yield no result. And empty values are passed:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="... soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username />
        <wsse:Password />
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Attempts to get existing headers prior to sending the request return nothing. So I created a header programatically and set it on the stub. It works, but now TWO security headers are sent, one with credentials and one "empty":

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="..." soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="...">
        <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>xxx</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce xmlns:wsse="...">8mTkXig00vZnqC2XlPWJ4A==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="...">2019-07-19T18:46:57.048Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="..." soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username />
        <wsse:Password />
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Why is it sending an empty one? Is there any way of removing it of getting access to it so I can modify it and not create a new header?

Answer (score 0):

Another developer in my team found out there was a UsernameHandler implementation class that added the security header which was configured via some apache configuration file on the classpath. Removed that and header no longer gets created.